# Sequelize query Or-ing where and include statements

Tags: javascript, sql, sequelize.js

I am trying make a Sequelize query that returns only records that match a **where clause** or **include wheres**. For example I have a user model that belongs to a person model. The user model has one field called username and the person model has a first and last name.

Example Query:

```
{
    "where": {
      "username": {
        "$iLike": "%s%"
      }
    },
    "include": [{
        "model": Person,
        "where": {
            "$or": [{
                "firstName": {
                    "$iLike": "%s%"
                }
            }, {
                "lastName": {
                    "$iLike": "%s%"
                }
            }]
        }
    }]
}
```

The query above matches records that have a username AND (firstname or lastname) matching "ilike" 's'. I am trying to achieve username OR (firstname or lastname).

I know how do use Or operators when working inside of a where but I want to use an Or on where or include. Is this possible? Do I use required false?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

try this:

```
{
where: {
  $or: [
    {
      userName: {
        $ilike: "%s%"
      }
    },
    {
      '$person.firstName$': {
        $ilike: "%s%"
      }
    },
    {
      '$person.lastName$': {
        $ilike: "%s%"
      }
    }
  ]
},
include: [
  {
    model: Person,
  }
]
}
```

Comment: Any idea how to do this on a model with a `hasMany` relationship? If there were more than one person, for example, this code wouldn't work. This works because there is only one person associated with this user model.

Comment: Just replace "person" with "persons" or whatever alias your are using. See https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/models-usage.html#top-level-where-with-eagerly-loaded-models