# How to convert postgreSQL to Sequelize format

Tags: node.js, postgresql, npm, sequelize.js

I have to try to convert my postgre sql query to orm concept using sequelize npm package, kindly guide me.

```
select * from "locationDepartmentMappings" as a
inner join "departments" as b on a."departmentId" = b.id
inner join "locations" as c on a."locationId" = c.id
where (
    b."departmentName" like '%Accounting%' or c."locationName" like '%Accounting%'
)
limit 1;
```

As per below code still i have getting

> error: column locationDepartmentMapping.department.departmentName does not exist

As @shivam mentioned i have tried depends mine below, can you what i need to changes,

```
        let ldv = await LocationDepartmentModel.findAll({
          include: [
            {
              model: LocationModel,
              as: "location",
              required: true,
            },
            {
              model: DepartmentModel,
              as: "department",
              required: true,
            }
          ],
          where: {
            $or: [
              {
                "department.departmentName": { like: `%${reqQueryName}%` }
              },
              { "location.locationName": { like: `%${reqQueryName}%` } }
            ]
          },
          limit:1
        });
```

Comment: Have you defined your model already? If so, include it in the question please.

Comment: @TheWildHealer, yes created,. [link]http://docs.sequelizejs.com, you wants to check?

Comment: @TheWildHealer, Thanks for pointing joins error.

Answer (score 0):

Sequelize has pretty good documentation on how to write queries using the orm syntax.
To start with, the above query would look something like

```
Model.locationDepartmentMappings.findAll({
  include: [
    {
      model: Model.departments
      where: {departmentName: {$like: '% Accounting%'}}
    },
    {
      model: Model.locations
      where: {locationName: {$like: '% Accounting%'}}
    }],
  limit: 1
})
```

What you should consider getting to above query is
1. Learn how to create sequelize [models](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/models-definition.html)
2. Learn [Associations](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/associations.html)
3. [Querying](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/querying.html)

There are a lot of great tutorials out there, which can help you get started, and are just a google search away!

Comment: Is the default where combination operator a `OR`? I think your query might do a `b."departmentName" like '%Accounting%' and c."locationName" like '%Accounting%'` instead of a `b."departmentName" like '%Accounting%' or c."locationName" like '%Accounting%'`

Comment: @shivam, we dont need inner join ```on a."departmentId" = b.id``` query?

Comment: Kitta: No we don't have to have the join explicitly written , Those are taken care on how you set up the association,

@TheWildHealer: Yes you are correct, this would do an AND.

Comment: So how would you do to have a `OR` between two associated models where? I'm curious about that too.

Answer (score 0):

Final with help got the solutions :

```
let ldData = await LocationDepartmentModel.findAll({
      include: [
        {
          model: LocationModel,
          as: "location",
          required: true
        },
        {
          model: DepartmentModel,
          as: "department",
          required: true
        }
      ],
      where: {
        $or: [
          { "$department.departmentName$": { like: `%${reqQueryName}%` } },
          { "$location.locationName$": { like: `%${reqQueryName}%` } }
        ]
      },
      limit: 1
    });
```

Courtesy for below :

[@shivam answer for joining tables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56287722/8300249)

[@ManjulSigdel answer for where condition include table column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49839119/8300249)